# DynamoDB query() versus getItem() for single-item retrieval based on the index

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

If I'm retrieving a single item from my table based on the indexed hash key, is there a performance difference between `query()` or `getItem()`?

Answer (score 64):

`getItem` will be faster

`getItem` retrieve via hash and range key is a 1:1 fit, the time it takes (hence performance) to retrieve it is limited by the hash and sharding internally.

Query results in a search on "all" range keys. It adds computational work, thus considered slower.

Edit: Just for quick comparison adding the following picture from this [blog entry](https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-scan-vs-query/).

[image: Decision diagram which retrieval function to use]

Comment: What is a range key? Do you mean sort key?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen back in the day (this answer is from 2012!) DynamoDB called it <Hash,Range>. Then around the time the document api was released, the conversation shifted to <Partition,Sort>..

Answer (score 30):

In Amazon's DynamoDB, your performances are **guaranteed** whatever the access method. (you pay for it).

There may be a **couple a milliseconds** differences on the DynamoDB servers themselves as suggested by Chen Harel but these are **negligible** because of the HTTP request RTT.

This said, it's a **good practice** to issue a `GET` instead of `QUERY` when you have enough informations to do so.

Comment: Those couple of milliseconds can make a huge difference at scale, even in the context of an HTTP request.  That 2-3ms additional latency to DynamoDB could mean 2-3ms time that a request remains open between your web server and your backend service, tying up resources.

Comment: It's good people are thinking of performance. When we talk about optimizations of 2-3ms, there are not many webservices around the world that really need to think of this optimization. 99% of all webservices will never even notice this little delay.

Answer (score 27):

As suggested by aws employee in one of the discussion, I quote:

> The latency of GetItem vs Query with limit=1 will be equivalent.

[AWS discussion link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=93743)

Comment: Link is outdated

Answer (score -1):

There is no performance difference between the two. The hash calculation in both the queries are done 1 by 1.
The latter, i.e., get item is just provided as an analogy to the JPA repository/spring findOne/findById to make wiring in Spring Bean wiring/ Hibernate configs easier.